# Versioning of SQL database and .net applications

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a .net application using sql server 2005 database. This is a very simple data entry application. But the client is using it for a very long time and speed of the application getting worst with the time as the size of database is growing.

Client is not ready to delete the previos data from the database but want to versioning it in different database so they could use it if they want it later and speed issue will also resolved as the actual database move old data to a different database.

So kindly guide me in the right direction to achieve this.

Partition table looks very effective way to solve the issue and after doing every if & else, i come to know that this is not available in express edition of sql server. Help me, i am even ready to move the db to sql server 2008 express edition for this feature, but this option is not available in sql 2008 express as well. Kindly suggest me some workaround around free sql server editions

Thanks

Comment: You probably want http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm or some better indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is possibly slightly off-topic, but I suggest rebuilding your indexes (assuming you have them, otherwise that's a different matter...) and ensuring your statistics are up to date.

Craate a regular maintenance task to do this.

Also, ensure you do not have any cursor based code that is giving you O(N^2) behaviour...

Comment: Agree, check index fragmentation levels. We once employed a DBA that didn't do this...